# Airflow DAG created using Taskflow failing with error: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to create a simple POC Airflow (2.2.3) DAG using Taskflow. Given below is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
import yaml
import sys
import logging    

sys.path.append('airflow/scripts/')
from etl_module import extract_data, load_data_catalog, transform_data

DAG_CONFIG_YAML = 'airflow/configs/test.yaml'
with open(DAG_CONFIG_YAML, 'r') as data:
    config = yaml.load(data, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

@dag(
    schedule_interval=config['dag_config']['schedule'], 
    start_date=config['dag_config']['start_date'],
    tags=['test'],
)
def test_daily_load_workflow():

    extract = task(extract_data.extract_data(config))
    transform = task(transform_data.transform_data(config))
    load = task(load_data_catalog.load_data_catalog(config))

    extract() >> transform() >> load()

test_daily_load_workflow_obj = test_daily_load_workflow()
```

The task functions (which contain only logging statements for now) are running when I try to run this file but it keeps failing towards the end and, consequently, does not get registered as a DAG.

Execution output:

```
[2021-12-28 19:38:16,659] {extract_data.py:5} INFO - extracting data
[2021-12-28 19:38:18,662] {extract_data.py:12} INFO - data extraction successful
[2021-12-28 19:38:18,662] {transform_data.py:5} INFO - transform / enrich data
[2021-12-28 19:38:20,665] {transform_data.py:11} INFO - data transformation successful
[2021-12-28 19:38:20,665] {load_data_catalog.py:5} INFO - final touch-ups / enrichments
[2021-12-28 19:38:22,668] {load_data_catalog.py:11} INFO - data catalog write successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/e/projects/airflow-poc/airflow/dags/test/test_daily_load_workflow.py", line 40, in <module>
    test_daily_load_workflow1 = test_daily_load_workflow()
  File "/mnt/e/projects/airflow-poc/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2984, in factory
    f(**f_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/e/projects/airflow-poc/airflow/dags/test/test_daily_load_workflow.py", line 37, in test_daily_load_workflow
    extract() >> transform() >> load()
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'
```

This *should* be a simple problem to solve but I am not able to see what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause of this issue but I changed the code to below and it started working! Essentially moved `task` decorator also into the definition in the scripts folder.

```
@dag(
    schedule_interval=config['dag_config']['schedule'], 
    start_date=config['dag_config']['start_date'],
    catchup=config['dag_config']['catch_up'], 
    tags=['test'],
    )
def test_daily_load_workflow():
    (
        extract_data.extract_data(config) >>
        transform_data.transform_data(config) >>
        load_data_catalog.load_data_catalog(config)
    )

test_daily_load_workflow = test_daily_load_workflow()
```